# Styled Components - dynamic styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, properties, styled-components

I learn how to use styled components in react I do step by step following the video. I have this piece of code I have a problem with this line and others too

```
color: ${(props) => (props.invalid ? "red" : "black")}
```

VS Code tells me this

> "Property 'invalid' may not exist on type
> 'ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes,
> HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes> & {
> ...; }, any>'. Did you mean 'onInvalid'?ts(2568)"

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
import "./CourseInput.css";

const FormControl = styled.div`
  margin: 0.5rem 0;

  & label {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    color: ${(props) => (props.invalid ? "red" : "black")}
  }

  & input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid ${(props) => (props.invalid ? "red" : "#ccc")};
    background: ${(props) => (props.invalid ? "red" : "transparent")}
    font: inherit;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
  }

  & input:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: #fad0ec;
    border-color: #8b005d;
  }
`;

const CourseInput = (props) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

  const goalInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    //set back true
    if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
      setIsValid(true);
    }
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (enteredValue.trim().length === 0) {
      //trim deletes white spacec overall
      setIsValid(false);
      return;
    }

    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      {/* <div className={`form-control ${!isValid ? "invalid" : ""}`}> */}
      <FormControl invalid={!isValid}>
        <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={goalInputChangeHandler} />
      </FormControl>
      {/* </div> */}
      <Button type="submit">Add Goal</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CourseInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **invalid** is not a prop that the div element knows by default it does not recognize it.

To overcome this, you can give FormControl props with the "$" key as follows:

```
<FormControl $invalid={!isValid}>
```

Then, inside FormControl:

```
color: ${(props) => (props.$invalid ? "red" : "black")}
```